# Using filter inside filter in dplyr gives unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `R 3.1.2`, `dplyr 0.4.0`.

I'm trying to use a `filter` within a `filter`, which sounds very simple and I don't understand why it doesn't give me the result I expect. This is code I wrote about 6 months ago and I'm fairly certain it worked, so either it stopped working because of an updated R version or `dplyr` or some other dependency. Anyway, here is some simple code that filters rows from df1 based on a condition that is found with a `filter` on a column in df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x = "A", y = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dplyr::filter(df1, x %in% (dplyr::filter(df2, y)$x))
```

I expect this to show the first row of `df1`, but instead I get

```
# [1] x
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

which I'm not sure what to make of. Why is it returning a vector AND an empty data.frame?

If I break up the filter code into two separate statements, I get what I expect

```
xval <- dplyr::filter(df2, y)$x
dplyr::filter(df1, x %in% xval)

#   x
# 1 A
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this behaviour is happening? I'm not saying it's a bug, but I don't understand it.

Comment: I can't really explain the *why*, but `filter(df1, x %in% (filter(df2, y) %>% .$x))` seems more appropriate in terms of the `dplyr` syntax, and produces the desired output

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that works, but it seems more verbose and a tiny bit less readable to me (though that's arguable). But I'll accept your answer :)  
You also answer another question I've always had - what's the proper dplyr way of extracting a column?  I sometimes used `filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% as.character` or `filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% first`.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I assume you are using dplyr 0.4.0? In 0.3.0.2 it doesn't work apparently. Another option would be `filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% inner_join(df1)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus - yes.  Just updated today actually

Comment: @daattali FWIW: (1) When I run: `filter(df1, x %in% filter(df2, y)$x)`, I don't get the same output as you, I get an error: `Error: incompatible expression in filter`. (2) The code works fine on `data.table`s: `dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)`; `dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)`; `dt1 %>% filter(x == (filter(dt2, y)$x))`, which may suggest that what's going on in the `data.frame` version is 'not expected'.

Comment: @daattali Regarding my (1), I must have messed up something in my R session. I do get the same output as you. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

It's a valid question, why your approach doesn't work (any more, apparently). I can't answer that but I would suggest a different approach, as commented above, which avoids nested function calls (`filter` *inside* another `filter`) which, IMO, is what dplyr is made for: being expressive by easy to read and understand syntax, from left to right, top to bottom.

So for your example, because the columns you are interested in are both named "x" you can do:

```
filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% inner_join(df1)
```

- Filter the df2 data by column "y"
- Select only column "x"
- Perform an inner_join with df1 on the common column ("x"). inner_join means: "return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, and all columns from x and y."

And if they were different, for example "z" and "x" you could use:

```
filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% inner_join(df1, by = c("z" = "x"))
```

---

As noted by Hadley in his comment below, it would be safer to use a `semi_join` instead of `inner_join` here. The documentation says:

> semi_join: return all rows from x where there are matching values in y,
>   keeping just columns from x.
>
> A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will
>   return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will
>   never duplicate rows of x.

Hence, you could do for the example case:

```
filter(df2, y) %>% select(x) %>% semi_join(df1)
```

Comment: A `semi_join()` would be safer than an `inner_join()` here

Comment: @hadley, That makes sense. I updated my answer and included the documentation on semi_join.