# R dplyr filter requires stored filter condition

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

When I filter a dataframe where the condition is made up of other filters, it doesn't seem to work. However, if I store the condition as a variable (`f` in the example), the filtering works fine. Can someone explain why this happens, and how to make something like Example 2 work? I would prefer to not store the filter condition as a variable.

```
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data set
df <- data.frame(Country = factor(c("Argentina", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil")), 
                 Type = factor(c("A", "A", "B", "C")))

# Only returns Brazil. No problem here.
f <- df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarise(nTypes = n_distinct(Type)) %>% 
  filter(nTypes==3) %>% 
  select(Country) %>% 
  droplevels() %>% 
  unlist()
# > f
#   Country 
# Brazil 
# Levels: Brazil


# Example 1 - Only returns rows of df where Country=="Brazil". No problem here.
df %>% filter(
  Country %in% (f
                )
  )
#   Country Type
# 1  Brazil    A
# 2  Brazil    B
# 3  Brazil    C


# Example 2 - Filter is equivalent to `f` but returns all rows of df, not just Brazil. No idea why!
df %>% filter(
  Country %in% (df %>% 
                  group_by(Country) %>% 
                  summarise(nTypes = n_distinct(Type)) %>% 
                  filter(nTypes==3) %>% 
                  select(Country) %>% 
                  droplevels() %>% 
                  unlist()
                )
  )
#     Country Type
# 1 Argentina    A
# 2    Brazil    A
# 3    Brazil    B
# 4    Brazil    C
```

Comment: What's exactly you're trying to get - Display the list of countries with Type that has count three?

Comment: Odd, I suspect it's an NSE name clash, but I'm not sure precisely how. Anyway, you can simplify the whole thing to `df %>% group_by(Country) %>% filter(n_distinct(Type) == 3)`

Comment: ...or just flip the order and pipe the code for `f` into `{ filter(df, Country %in% .) }`

Comment: @amrrs I'm trying to get the same output that Example 1 gives, but using the method shown in Example 2. That is, without storing the filtering condition as a variable

Comment: @alistaire Your first comment works just fine! I thought I might be overcomplicating it. Still, it is curious that the examples in my question occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure why you are getting unexpected results, based on this answer: [Using filter inside filter in dplyr gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937273/using-filter-inside-filter-in-dplyr-gives-unexpected-results) a way to get desired result after `filter`ing is to use `inner_join`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarise(nTypes = n_distinct(Type)) %>% 
  filter(nTypes==3) %>% 
  select(Country) %>% inner_join(.,df)
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = "Country"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Country   Type
   <fctr> <fctr>
1  Brazil      A
2  Brazil      B
3  Brazil      C
```

Comment: This works, thanks @amrrs! I'll also note for any future readers that @alistaire's solution in the comments works too and in my opinion is easier to read, understand, and most likely faster as doesn't need to do a join.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer with that also if you wish!